# gwt custom widget with child elements configuration in UIBinder (like CustomButton)

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've faced with a task to create custom widget, it has container behavior -- 3 panels inside.
And i would like to use it in general UIBinder way like [CustomButton](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html)

```
 <u:MyWidget>
   <u:image><g:Image .../></u:image>
   <u:mainContent><g:Panel.../></u:mainContent>
 </u:MyWinget>
```

Is it possible to define that custom child elements somehow or maybe it is predefined thing in the UIBuilder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Correct way to do it is to use the [UiChild](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiChild.html) annotation.

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite {
  public MyWidget() {
    // ...
  }

  @UiChild( tagname = "image" )
  void addImage(Image image) {
    // ...
  } 

  @UiChild( tagname = "mainContent" )
  void addMainContent(Widget contentWidget) {
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas - But how do you do this generically? For example if all child panels implemented myInnerPanel, how could I access that child? The docs say that this tag name must exactly match the method name. Is there a work around?

Comment: okay, got it working. As long as my generic type, say MyAbstractWidget is extended by the child of the 'customtag' tag, then in the @ UiChild method, I can upcast from Widget to MyAbstractWidget without issue. That way the @ UiChild method and parent widget can handle any properly formed future child of 'customtag.'